# Who makes this cool Arduino display shield, and what model is it?

Tags: lcd, shields

Anyone recognize Mfgr/model of this display that reads: "Wireless Internet Of Things".  The Arduino board is a WIOT.

I've been looking and looking for a source for Arduino display like this, but cannot find.

[image]

Comment: If you google for "Arduino OLED Blue" you get hundreds of similar displays.

Answer (score 3):

That will be an SSD1306 based blue OLED display with SPI interface. There's lots of them around by lots of different people. Some are I2C interface, and some of those have a "broken" I2C interface that doesn't send ACKs (especially cheap ones on eBay) and need a special ACK-less Software I2C implementation.

The SPI ones, of course, won't suffer from that problem.

They are generally 0.96" diagonal, and that one, I think, is 96x39 pixels (or it may be 128x64).